# disable dropdownlist value selected and get the next value of dropdown list

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HyK5A.png)

```
  <td>Choose Position</td>
<td><SELECT NAME="position" id="position" onclick="getPosition(this.value)">
<OPTION VALUE="select">select
<?php 
//loop through all table rows
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($positions)){
echo "<OPTION VALUE=$row[position_name]>$row[position_name]"; 
//mysql_free_result($positions_retrieved);
//mysql_close($link);
}
?>
</SELECT></td>
<td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="See Candidates" /></td>
```

i need to disable the value of a selected dropdown list and get the next value of the next dropdown list value when the radio button is selected how can i do that? please help

```
  if (isset($_POST['Submit']))
  {
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['candidate_name']."</td>";

echo "<td>" .$row['candidate_gender']."</td";

echo "<td>" . $row['candidate_grade']."</td>";

echo "<td>" .$row['candidate_section']."</td";

       Print '<td><img src="date:image/jpeg;base64,' .base64_encode($row['image']).'"height="60 width="75 /></td>';


  echo "<td><input type='radio' name='vote' value='$row[candidate_name]' onclick='getVote(this.value)' /></td>";
 echo "</tr>";  
 }

 mysql_free_result($result);
 mysql_close($link);

   }
 else
 // do nothing
 ?>
 <tr>
```

Comment: I don't see any radios. Plus, you question is tagged jquery but I don't see any, show us your entire code.

Comment: echo "<td><input type='radio' name='vote' value='$row[candidate_name]' onclick='getVote(this.value)' /></td>";

Comment: i also add the picture on how it looks like. what should i do? please help. this is for voting when the user already vote using radio button i want it to change its value in dropdown list to the next value after the radio button has been selected

Comment: Please help what should i do\

Comment: help me please :(

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are trying to achieve. The following has been done using Jquery and I removed intrusive javascript that you were having.

```js
$('input:radio').each(function() {
    $(this).on('click', function(e) {
        $('#position option[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]').prop('selected', true);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Choose Position
<SELECT NAME="position" id="position">
    <OPTION VALUE="none">Please select</option>
    <OPTION VALUE="name1">some value</option>
    <OPTION VALUE="name2">another value</option>
    <OPTION VALUE="name3">yet another value</option>
</SELECT>

<input type='radio' name='vote' value='name1' />
<input type='radio' name='vote' value='name2' />
<input type='radio' name='vote' value='name3' />
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="See Candidates" />
```